# How to remove page number locations being added to bibliography entries

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am writing my thesis in Overleaf, using the IEEE reference style and the BibTeX package for the bibliography. The bibliography entries generated have additional text at the end, it would appear it is including which page(s) the particular citation comes from. Any help removing them would be greatly appreciated, and I have included an image of my PDF to show what this looks like. Thank you.[image]

EDIT: The problem has been solved. My `includes.tex` files uses two packages, backref and pagebackref, which were responsible for adding the "pages" and their numbers for each citation entry. Include these if you want these pages labels, remove them if you do not. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] which we can  use as a starting point to work on an answer for you

Comment: Are you maybe using the `backref` option somewhere?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, I am using the backref and pagebackref packages.  I will admit, this was from a thesis template I got from someone from my university, so I was not aware of all the little things they have incorporated. I will check out these two packages to see if removing them solves my problem and/or breaks my project. Thank you!

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If not, please make a [mre] so we can see the code that causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to just edit the .bib file, and remove all lines with "pages = ... ". If the bib file doesn't specify them, then bibtex won't create entries for it.

E.g., in

```
@article{dubey2014survey,
  title={A survey of high level frameworks in block-structured adaptive mesh refinement packages},
  author={Dubey, Anshu and Almgren, Ann and Bell, John and Berzins, Martin and Brandt, Steve and Bryan, Greg and Colella, Phillip and Graves, Daniel and Lijewski, Michael and L{\"o}ffler, Frank and others},
  journal={Journal of Parallel and Distributed Computing},
  volume={74},
  number={12},
  pages={3217--3227},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

just remove the 'pages' line.

If you want to do it programmatically you'd have to edit the .bst file (IEEEtran.bst if i remember correctly), but that's not for the faint of heart, so I'd recommend the easier method.

Comment: Sorry I may have been vague, I do not want to remove the page numbers, I want to remove where at the end of each citation it says which page in my work the citations appear on. I don't believe it would be an issue with the "pages= { ... }" entries in my articles. I have used the IEEE citation format before, which is why this perplexes me.

Comment: Ah, I see; I misread that. I think those are 'backrefs'; have a look at this previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20133/remove-hyper-reference-back-reference-in-bibliography